# How do I call a variable in another function with PHP?

Tags: php, html, function

Hello I am trying to call a variable form a previous function into my next function. I tried using the global but I could not get it to call the variable from the previous function. How can I call the $hisname or $shorter variable in the function called "location"?

```
<?php
    function name( $hisname) {
    global $shorter;
    $shorter = str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($hisname));
?>

<p>
    <?php print $hisname; ?>
<Br>
    <?php print $shorter; ?>
</p>

<?php
    }
?>

    <?php name('Mike Smith'); ?>

<?php 
    function location($place) {
?>

<p>
    <?php print ($hisname) ?> lives in <?php print $place; ?>
</p>

<?php
    }
 ?>

    <?php location('New York'); ?>
```

You can see a demo here [demo on viper-7](http://viper-7.com/v2eseE)

Comment: Mixing php and html like this makes a horrible mess - dont do it. have your functions return strings, and echo the return value where you call the function

Comment: I'd use a class for this.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do that, if you can provide a link to something clear that would be helpful, thanks. And I am unaware on how classes work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
global $shorter;
function name($hisname) {

    $shorter = str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($hisname));
    return $shorter;
    ?>



    <?php
}
?>

<?php $hisname = name('Mike Smith');
?>

<p>
        <?php print $hisname; ?>
        <Br>
        <?php print $shorter; ?>
    </p>

<?php

function location($place, $hisname) {
    ?>

    <p>


        <?php print ($hisname) ?> lives in <?php print $place; ?>
    </p>

    <?php
}
?>

<?php location('New York', $hisname); ?>
```

Comment: `name()` does not return a value

Comment: with the line     <?php print ($hisname = "Mike Smith") ?>  , I did not test it but I wanted to get the variable from the last function.  I want it to be dynamic in a way. This seems like I am writing it out again and that is what I am trying to avoid. thanks

Comment: which is your last function?? `name()` ??

Comment: I am talking about the function name.  We already established that the name was Mike Smith.  so whenever I write out <?php echo $shorter; ?> the name mikesmith should be printed.   In the function location I want the variable from the last function to be used.

Comment: @okok, for that you have to return the value from your `name()`, i have edited my answer, check that.

Comment: nice, this is almost spot on. Any reason why the $hisname and $shorter are not printing inside the <p> tags?  I notce when I remove "return $shorter;" it works but then it is not printing it in the next function.

Comment: @okok Sorry, variables are not set when you are echoing them. See the answer for update

Comment: hmm, but doesn't print the other variable. And if i decide to add another variable like $food. I am unable to get it to print now http://viper-7.com/Jj0OEo

Comment: The way you are doing it is wrong. FIrst time you are not passing 2nd parameter. See that, ANd $food ?? e=where are you assigning the value to it?? Thats y its not working.

Comment: @okok see this how to use global variables.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp and, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php and, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code. hope you will get concept

```
<?php
function name( $hisname)
{
global $shorter;
$shorter = str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($hisname));
return $hisname;
}
?>

    <?php $name = name('Mike Smith'); echo $name; ?>

<?php 
    function location($place) {
    global $name;
?>

<p>
    <?php echo $name; ?> lives in <?php print $place; ?>
</p>

<?php
    }
 ?>

    <?php location('New York'); ?>
```

Comment: As usual, the night mare `semicolon` missing in return statement.

Comment: yes i think the error was with `semicolon` i edited my answer now

Comment: Seems like I am having to input the name 'Mike Smith' again. I am trying to avoid that. I want the name to be grabbed from the last function.

Comment: actually you have many methods to do so, but the easiest way is this.. ok i am editing my answer check it after a while, check line 8,11,14 of my answer now

Comment: almost there. take a look at http://viper-7.com/XOOe2Q When I have two variables (I added the food) i cannot seem to get it to work with  <?php $name = name('Mike Smith'); echo $name; ?>  . Where would the food go.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it working. Ended up using global and calling the variable on both functions. This seemed to get the job done easily.
Thanks for the help anyways.

```
<p> <?php echo $hisname; ?> likes to eat <?php echo $food; ?> <p>
<p> <?php echo $shorter; ?> <p>

<?php
   }
 ?>

<?php name('Mike Smith', 'Apples'); ?>


<?php 
    function location($place) {
    global $shorter;
 ?>

<p>
    <?php echo $shorter; ?> lives in <?php print $place; ?>

</p>

<?php
    }
?>

<?php location('New York'); ?>
```

[Demo Here](http://viper-7.com/4wkIAJ)